# R | Merging rows before and after

Tags: r

I have two data sets the looks like this

```
df
Region   Quarter   Review Date
North    Q1        2019-02-01
North    Q2        2019-05-01
South    Q1        2019-01-15
South    Q3        2019-08-20

sales
Region   Date          Sales
North    2019-01-25    20,500
North    2019-01-27    17,450
North    2019-02-01    31,000
North    2019-02-05    16,700
...
South    2019-08-16    2,300
South    2019-08-17    1,560
South    2019-08-20    3,400
South    2019-08-25    7,200
```

I want to create a new dataframe that takes 'df', adds a new column Sales and also picks sales for two days before and after the review date from dataframe 'sales'. The dates in 'sales' are not in sequence and are random for different region and quarters. The resulting dataframe shoud look like this

```
final df
    Region   Quarter   Review Date   Sales
    North    Q1        2019-01-25    20,500
    North    Q1        2019-01-27    17,450
    North    Q1        2019-02-01    31,000
    North    Q1        2019-02-05    16,700
    North    Q1        2019-02-07    23,400
    ...
    South    Q3        2019-08-16    2,300
    South    Q3        2019-08-17    1,560
    South    Q3        2019-08-20    3,400
    South    Q3        2019-08-25    7,200
    South    Q3        2019-08-29    4,350
```

I can get the sales on review date using merge but don't know how I can pick up the dates and sales above and below that from the second dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can try joining `df` by `df2` by `'Region'` column and for each `Region`, `Quarter` and `ReviewDate` value select 2 rows above and below where `ReviewDate == Date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'Region') %>%
  group_by(Region, Quarter, ReviewDate) %>%
  slice({i <- which(ReviewDate == Date);(i-2):(i+2)})
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a home-grown `leadlag` function for a bit now, I think it can be used here. It allows arbitrary leading and lagging.

```r
leadlag <- function(lgl, bef = 1, aft = bef) {
  n <- length(lgl)
  bef <- min(n, max(0, bef))
  aft <- min(n, max(0, aft))
  befx <- if (bef > 0) sapply(seq_len(bef), function(b) c(tail(lgl, n = -b), rep(FALSE, b)))
  aftx <- if (aft > 0) sapply(seq_len(aft), function(a) c(rep(FALSE, a), head(lgl, n = -a)))
  rowSums(cbind(befx, lgl, aftx), na.rm = TRUE) > 0
}
```

Simple example:

```r
vec <- 1:20
vec[leadlag(vec %% 10 == 1)] # 1, 11, as well as +/- 1
# [1]  1  2 10 11 12
vec[leadlag(vec %% 10 == 1, 2)] # 1, 11, as well as +/- 2
# [1]  1  2  9 10 11 12
vec[leadlag(vec %% 10 == 1, 0, 2)] # 1, 11, as well as none before and 2 after
# [1]  1  2  3 11 12 13
```

In this application, similar to @RonakShah's,

```r
df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'Region') %>%
  group_by(Region, Quarter, ReviewDate) %>%
  filter(leadlag(ReviewDate == Date))
```